# Password validation is not working in the login form

Tags: javascript, passwords

Password validation is not working in the login form. Here is my code:

```
function verifyPassword() {
  var str = document.getElementById("t1").value;
  if (str.match(/[a-z]/g) &&
    str.match(/[A-Z]/g) &&
    str.match(/[0-9]/g) &&
    str.match(/[^a-zA-Z\d]/g) &&
    str.length >= 8)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Show how you're calling the function.

Comment: FYI, generally `if (condition) return true; else return false;` can be written as simply `return condition;`

Comment: There's no need for the `g` flag when calling `match()`.

Comment: <div class="txt_field">
                    <input type="password" id="t1" value="" required>
                    <span></span>
                    <label>Password</label>

Comment: Nothing there calls `verifyPassword()`

Comment: <form action="adminpage.html" onclick="verifyPassword()">
                <div class="txt_field">
                    <input type="text" required>
                    <span></span>
                    <label>Username</label>
                </div>
                <div class="txt_field">
                    <input type="password" id="t1" value="" required>
                    <span></span>
                    <label>Password</label>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Login">

Comment: Don't try to put code in comments, edit the question.

Comment: The return value of the `onclick` function isn't used for anything.

Comment: Ok, how will I call the function??

Answer (score 0):

You should call the function in the password field's `change` event and/or the form's submit event, not the form's `click` event. And you need to test the return value and do something.

```
document.getElementById('t1').addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (!verifyPassword()) {
        alert("Invalid password");
    }
}
document.getElementByTagName('form')[0].addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    if (!verifyPassword()) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Invalid password");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below you have a cleaner code and is checking your password, you must have: lowercase, uppercase character, and a number. The `^` symbol means that the password must be in this order: lowercase, uppercase, number and must be more than 8 characters.

The syntax `?=.*[x]` means that you must have the condition `x` in your string.

Your old code was only checking if your string has any of *these* (lowercase, uppercase characters, numbers) but didn't put the condition that you must have all of these and for your password system this was useless.

```js
function verifyPassword() {
  var str = document.getElementById("t1").value;
  var regEx = new RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.{8,})");
  
  if (regEx.test(str) &&
    str.length >= 8)
    console.log("good")
  else
    console.log("bad")
}
```

```html
<div class="txt_field"> 
  <input type="password" id="t1" value="" required> 
  <label>Password</label>
  <button onclick="verifyPassword()">Verify</button>
</div>
```